# Start debug window on other monitor than the Godot editor

Tags: editors, screen, godot-4

When starting my game for debugging, I'd like to have **the *game* pop up at my second monitor** (still in "Windowed" mode), instead of on top of the Godot editor window itself. I've tried several things to get this to work:

- Drag the debug window to another screen, restart it (hoping it'd "remember" its last position)
- In Project Settings under Display, Window: try "Primary Screen Center" with `0`, `1`, `2` for "Initial Screen"
- In Project Settings under Display, Window: try "Other Screen Center" with `0`, `1`, `2` for "Initial Screen"
- Same as above but now with "Fullscreen" (which I don't want, but just for testing purposes)
- Same as above but now with the Godot editor on my other monitor
- Search Project Settings for "Monitor" and "Screen" to find other related options
- Go through all options in the "Debug" menu (none seem relevant)

None of these worked. Which probably means I'm doing something wrong because "Other Screen Center" should at least have *some* effect, according to the tooltips even exactly the effect I'm looking for?

I've tried searching online but I mainly land on ["Multi-monitor editor support"](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/28) or similar threads. Although that feature would also be nice, I don't need full multi-monitor and floating window support for the editor; just the game needs to go to my second monitor.

I'm running **Godot 4.0** on **Windows 10 Pro x64**, and have **two 2560x1440 monitors**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look in the "**Editor**" menu, option "***Editor Settings***...", then **Run > Window Placement > Screen**.

Comment: btw,Fristly I tried and failed to find the answer too, then post on godotengine's QA. other answer it, I tried & it works.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for taking the time to post an answer. I had not realized there were also "Editor Settings" when I wrote the question, only knew about the "Project Settings". This is exactly what I needed.